# Удаление элемента из контейнера используя синтаксис цикла for c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Возможно ли, используя синтаксис диапазонного цикла `for`:

```
for(auto& i: mapR) {
    // ...
}
```

для обхода контейнера, удалить текущий элемент из контейнера, если он, например, попадает под некое условие? Или придется использовать версию с итераторами, как показано ниже?

```
for(auto i = mapR.begin(); i != mapR.end(); ) {   
    // ... 
    i = mapR.erase(i); 
}
```

Comment: В любом случае в цикле тебе придётся проходить по всему контейнеру, а вот в цикле ты можешь уже прописать любое условие для удаления элемента.

Comment: Вообще-то, как мне кажется (на 100% не уверен, потому и не в ответ), что при удалении текущие итераторы инвалидируются, так что оба варианта будут некорректны. Используйте `remove_if` с последующим `erase`, если он нужен...

Comment: @Harry .erase() в контенерах обычно возвращает итератор на следующий элемент, так что ничего не инвалидируется

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Стандарт определяет range-based for loop, эквивалентным следующему коду:

```
{
    auto && __range = range - init;
    for(auto __begin = begin - expr,
        __end = end - expr;
        __begin != __end;
        ++__begin) {
        for-range-declaration = *__begin;
        statement
    }
}
```

Как вы можете видеть, внутри используются итераторы, поэтому, внутри цикла, *нельзя* использовать код, который может сделать итераторы недействительным.

Отвечая на Ваш вопрос, нет — нельзя удалять элементы из C++ контейнеров, в которых данная операция приводит к недействительным итераторам.

Comment: Можно удалить элемент (правда, это будет довольно криво с учетом работы со значениями), и тут же сделать выход из цикла по `break`.

Comment: @alexolut, ну это уже из разряда: «смотрите как я могу!»

Comment: Да. Об этом и речь.

Answer (score 4):

Диапазонная версия цикла `for` вида `for ( for-range-declaration : expression ) statement` [эквивалентна](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ranged#1) следующему коду:

```
{
    auto && __range = range-init;
    for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
               __end = end-expr;
             __begin != __end;
             ++__begin ) {
        for-range-declaration = *__begin;
        statement
    }
}
```

Поэтому формально с элементами контейнера внутри диапазонного цикла `for` можно было бы делать всё то же самое, что и с элементами внутри эквивалентного ему обычного цикла `for`. Т.е. учитывая все последствия [инвалидации](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) ссылок/итераторов/указателей соответствующего контейнера. Но проблема в том, что диапазонная версия `for` не предоставляет программисту доступа непосредственно к итератору и работать можно только со значениями или ссылками. Всё это приводит к тому, что искать элемент надо по-новой, а если контейнер содержит несколько эквивалентных элементов, то нельзя достоверно сказать, что удаляется именно тот элемент, на котором в данный момент находится итератор цикла.

В итоге получаем, что **диапазонная версия `for` не предусмотрена для модификации контейнера** в плане вставки/удаления элементов. Такой цикл следует использовать только для перебора значений или их модификации.

Answer (score 2):

В любом случае ваш вариант удаления некорректен, т.к. при удалении формально происходит инвалидация итераторов.

Вот ваш вариант, который вы считаете корректным:

```
vector<int> tst{ 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5};

for(auto i = tst.begin(); i != tst.end(); ++i)
{
    if (*i <= 3) i = tst.erase(i);
}

for(auto i: tst) cout << i << endl;
```

Получаем (Visual C++ 2015) - 1
2
2
3
4
4
4
5
5
5

C GCC - та же история: http://ideone.com/MctlQw

**Update** Предложенный вариант

```
if (*i <= 3) i = tst.erase(i); else ++i;
```

лично у меня вызывает неприятие по причине

1. стиля (вынесение инкремента из заголовка цикла, на мой взгляд, никак не способствует восприятию текста).
2. переносимости. По крайней мере [тут четко говорится](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase), что `erase`

> invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the
>   erase, including the end() iterator.

С другой стороны, с интересом выслушаю и другие мнения, поскольку опять же формально, при перевычислении `end()` данный способ в принципе должен срабатывать.

Comment: for(auto i = tst.begin(); i != tst.end(); )
{
    if (*i <= 3) { i = tst.erase(i)} else{ ++i;};
}

Comment: так попробуйте. убрать инкремент в цикле, т.к. при удалении будем проскакивать тот итератор который присвоили

Comment: Не уверен в переносимости вашего решения. Формально может быть контейнер, который после удаления может выполнить сжатие памяти. И, простите уж за прямоту, но такой стиль мне категорически не нравится - перекидывать инкремент из заголовка...

Comment: @xttz Стандарта у меня под рукой нет, но вот - Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator (отсюда: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase )

Comment: все работает и ничего не инвалидируется  но удалять таким образом элементы из вектора по моему полная клиника, учитывая что он при каждом erase перевыделяет себе память. особенно круто если размер vector пару миллионов элементов, а удалить нужно несколько тысяч.

Comment: и не надо привязываться к vector возьмите хотябы list который и создан для того чтоб элементы можно было удалять без влияния на остальные.

Comment: Тогда о чем мы вообще говорим? О том, что в каких-то определенных случаях (конкретный контейнер, конкретная реализация) какой-то конкретный код применим? Это очевидно. Или о  принципиальном решении той или иной задачи?

Comment: Коллеги, (@xttz) по сути Вы говорите об одной очень важной вещи, а именно, стоит ли вообще программировать на этом языке.

Comment: @avp У каждого языка есть свои... скажем так, традиции. По-русски тоже можно говорить культурно, можно матом, можно на сленге...