# Насколько корректно удаление элеметнов из std::map прямо во время её обхода в range-based цикле

Tags: c++, c++17

Есть std::map которую необходимо обойти и удалить некоторые элементы если их значение удовлетворяет определённому условию. Обычный обход в tange-based цикле и удаление элементов прямо в цикле работает (что для меня полная неожиданность). Но насколько такие действия вообще корректны? Насколько я знаю такие циклы это просто обёртка обхода по итератору. Почему итератор после удаления значения не сдыхает?

```
int main() {
    std::map<int, string> some_map;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) some_map.emplace(i, std::to_string(i));
    for (auto& [first, second] : some_map) if (!second.compare("6")) some_map.erase(first);
    for (auto [first, second] : some_map) std::cout << first<< " " << second << std::flush << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Возможные дубликаты: [Удаление элемента списка при for (auto& i : list)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/557098/176217) и [Удаление элемента из контейнера используя синтаксис цикла for c++11](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/502487/176217).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как написано в [документации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase), *"References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected."*

Это означает, что ваш цикл некорректен, поскольку он удаляет тот самый элемент, на который указывает скрытый итератор. То, что он у вас работает как задумывалось - не более чем случайность.

Однако, если заранее передвинуть итератор на следующий элемент, он останется валидным, и цикл будет корректным:

```
for (auto it = some_map.begin(); it != some_map.end(); ) {
    auto & [first, second] = *it++;
    if (!second.compare("6")) 
        some_map.erase(first);
}
```

Также можно воспользоваться примером из документации:

```
for (auto it = some_map.begin(); it != some_map.end(); ) {
    auto & [first, second] = *it;
    if (!second.compare("6")) 
        it = some_map.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Эти действия некорректны. Итератор сдыхает. А сама программа погружается в пучину неопределенного поведения.

Comment: понятно, спасибо =)